# I need to validate a query parameter

Tags: php, laravel, validation

The query parameter is status
It's value can be status=draft or status=draft,sent&

How can I validate that the status is draft, sent or approved?

I was using this rule

```
'status'    => 'nullable|in:draft,approved,declined,sent'
```

To validate statuses invidually.
How can I validate if there are 2 status and they're valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend Laravel validation in your `AppServiceProvider` in `boot()` method like so

```
Validator::extend('check_status', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $valid_statuses = ['draft', 'approved', 'declined', 'sent'];
    $requested_statuses = explode(",", $value);
    $array_diff = array_diff($requested_statuses, $valid_statuses);

    $validator->addReplacer('check_status', function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) use ($array_diff) {
         return str_replace(':statuses', implode(", ", $array_diff), $message);
    });

    return empty($array_diff);
}, 'Statuses [:statuses] are not valid');
```

i have added a custom validation error message that will print all not valid statuses.

in your controller you will add

```
'status' => 'nullable|check_status'
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I wanted to do it through the validate() method provided by Laravel, but I wasn't sure how to validate values inside of an array.
I was converting `draft,sent` to array and validate that but I couldn't make it work

Comment: I think there is a way to do it inside `validate()` using `regex` but i'm not sure how to do.